# How to center a picture using html source in RichText of QML?

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I want to center a picture in QML using `RichText` . I tried `<center>` tag and `text-align` attribute. none of them works.

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQml.Models 2.1
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 1.2


ApplicationWindow{
    width: Screen.width; height: Screen.height; color: "#d5d6d8"
    visible:true
    Rectangle {
        color: "#33cc94"
        width: parent.width; height: parent.height
        id : main

        Flickable {
            id:textArea
            anchors.fill: parent
            contentHeight: textBrowser.height
            contentWidth: textBrowser.width
            enabled: false
            Text {
                id:textBrowser
                textFormat: Text.RichText
               // visible:false
             //   text: "<center><img src=\"Icons/TroopCards/ArchersCard.png\"  /></center>";
                text: "<p style=\"text-align:center\">
                          <img  src=\"Icons/TroopCards/ArchersCard.png\" />
                       </p>
                       <p style=\"text-align:center\">Some text at middle</p>";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And result :

[image: Left aligned image!]

How can I center an image using html in QML ?!

Comment: Do you have to use a `Text` item to display the picture?

Comment: @Mitch yes this is very simplified example

Comment: Depending on your platform, you may have much better luck with full-blown webbrowser components (look into http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwebengine-index.html for desktop, for example).

Comment: @mlvljr webengine is not available in android

Comment: Which is what I suspected, you should have mentioned that though :)

Comment: Android has its own webview: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwebview-index.html actually , so I'd check that first. Text items implement a rather limited HTML subset...

Comment: Using `text: "<p align=\"center\" style=\"color:#00000000\">.<img src=\"test.png\" align=\"center\"></p>
           <p align=\"center\">Some more text</p>"` trick may do it (or not, depending on what is necessary :)) Good luck :)

Answer (score 2):

If you need to put something in the center of a block, specify the width (and height) of the block so the program can calculate the center position. For example, set the size of the text block to `Screen` size:

```
Text {
    id:textBrowser
    textFormat: Text.RichText
    width: Screen.width
    height: Screen.height
    text: "<p style=\"text-align:center\"><img src=\"Icons/TroopCards/ArchersCard.png\" /></p>
           <p style=\"text-align:center\">Some text at middle</p>";
}
```

And the image is now centered in your window (since your `ApplicationWindow` has the same width and height).

......No, it doesn't. Maybe there are some bugs in the rich text processor, or maybe it does not support image alignment in rich text at all. If you really want to use rich text to put an image in the center of the text block, here is a simple workaround: put an `&nbsp;` (space character) before your image tag.

```
Text {
    id:textBrowser
    textFormat: Text.RichText
    width: Screen.width
    height: Screen.height
    text: "<p style=\"text-align:center\">&nbsp;<img src=\"Icons/TroopCards/ArchersCard.png\" /></p>
           <p style=\"text-align:center\">Some text at middle</p>";
}
```

And the image is almost in the center of the text block.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Text {
            id:textBrowser
            anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.hrizontalcenter
            textFormat: Text.RichText
            text: "<p style=\"text-align:center\">
                      <img  src=\"Icons/TroopCards/ArchersCard.png\" />
                   </p>
                   <p style=\"text-align:center\">Some text at middle</p>";
        }
```

Comment: `horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter` works. but it make all items at center and remove other alignments :(

Answer (score 0):

Try this as `text` parameter of `TextArea` (`Text` with `textFormat: Text.RichText`):

```
<p align=\"center\"><img src=\"Icons/TroopCards/ArchersCard.png\"/></p>
<p style=\"text-align:center\">Some text at middle</p>
```

Comment: not working ... try this as text (http://paste.ofcode.org/WNaxtqZUUnMMHPbsMMbY98)

Comment: Complete file is something like this (docx page that I convert to htm everything work correctly except that image http://paste.ofcode.org/xFHgBxs7wu3iBigUA2qJ5N

Comment: In office : http://i.stack.imgur.com/8XfdB.png and result in qml : http://i.stack.imgur.com/ZdyYh.png

Answer (score 0):

For the anchors you could calculate the horizontal center offset of Text element by using the window width (main) minus the surrounding element (parent) width divided by two. So, add these three lines:

```
horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
anchors.horizontalCenterOffset: (main.width - parent.width) / 2
anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
```

Result:

[image: result]